# Remove white space from part of a string

Tags: c#

I have the text:

```
SMS \r\n\t•    Map - locations of
```

How can I remove all of the white space between • and the first following character?

The above example should result in

```
SMS \r\n\t•Map - locations of
```

Comment: what code have you got to try this yourself so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a regular expression it can be done like so:

```
var input = "SMS \r\n\t•    Map - locations of";

var regexPattern = @"(?<=•)\s+(?=\w)";
var cleanedInput = Regex.Replace(input, regexPattern, String.Empty);
```

This will replace any whitespace between • and the first word character with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "SMS \r\n\t•    Map - locations of";
string[] temp = s.Split('•');
s = temp[0]+temp[1].TrimStart(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regex:

```
string toInsertBetween = string.Empty;
string toReplace = "SMS \r\n\t•    Map - locations of";
string res = Regex.Replace(toReplace, "•[ ]+([^ ])", "•" + toInsertBetween + "$1");
```

Comment: Consider using `\s` to match whitespace characters and `\S` to match non-whitespace characters.